# Echo JSON/XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, json, api, echo

I'm using the last.fm API to get a user's recent tracks and it returns either a JSON string or an XML document.

[XML format](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=rj&limit=5&api_key=cf9021419b97b1e4611d580e6304e5be)

[JSON format](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=rj&limit=5&api_key=cf9021419b97b1e4611d580e6304e5be&format=json)

Which should I use? and I want to get the track names to echo using PHP, how should I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Primary opinion based, use `json_decode` or the SimpleXML extension. Both return an object, in which you can get track names from.

Comment: Looking at the JSON, it seems to be `['recenttracks']['track'][#]['name']` where `#` is looped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer Json

1- Using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) you can get the json.

2- Decode Json using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

3- Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to get the value you want

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=rj&limit=5&api_key=cf9021419b97b1e4611d580e6304e5be&format=json');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

if (is_array($parsed_json) && !empty($parsed_json)) {
  //check if is array and not null
  $track = $parsed_json->recenttracks->track;

  foreach ($track as $key) {
    echo $key->name . '<br>';
  }
} else {
  echo 'No data available';
}
```

**Output:**

Booty Swing - Original

Social Know-How

Looking At The Sun

Gett Off

Afraid to Shoot Strangers

Answer (score 0):

Basically i depends on whether you are already using a very good xml parser or not, and whether you are more comfortable with xml than json. 
But from a third person view, it will be very easy to use the JSON representation with "json_decode" function in php which will give you directly an object which is equivalent to the json representation.

According to me using JSON with json_decode will be the easiest solution. For more info check php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use **json** simply like,

```
$jsonArr=json_decode($yourjson,true);
if(isset($jsonArr['recenttracks']['track']) and !empty($jsonArr['recenttracks']['track']))
{
    foreach($jsonArr['recenttracks']['track'] as $track){
        echo $track['name'].'<br/>';;
    }
}
```